# How get selected option label from a dropdown list?

Tags: jsp, servlets, drop-down-menu, label

I am developing a simple web application in which I want to take the option label of a dropdown list in HTML page on the next JSP page. I am using MVC pattern and thus Servlet as a controller will be redirecting (forwarding?) the request to JSP view.

The `request.getParameter()` gives me only the option value. But in my case the option value and label are different. How can I get the option label?

Comment: There is no way you can get it back from the JSP. You have to maintain a mapping as suggested by the BalusC's answer.

Comment: @XCoder : can we write a seperate POJO for a dropdown box and access the value selected on the next JSP page using <jsp:formBean> , <jsp:setProperty> , <jsp:getProperty> ?? Is it possible? Kindly reply..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to maintain a mapping of option values and labels in the server side. E.g. inside some `ServletContextListener` or perhaps servlet's `init()`:

```
Map<String, String> countries = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
countries.put("CW", "Curaçao");
countries.put("NL", "The Netherlands");
countries.put("US", "United States");
// ...

servletContext.setAttribute("countries", countries);
```

When you put it in the application scope as `${countries}`, then you can display it as follows:

```
<select name="country">
  <c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country">
    <option value="${country.key}">${country.value}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

This way you will be able to obtain the label in the server side as follows:

```
Map<String, String> countries = (Map<String, String>) getServletContext().getAttribute("countries");
// ...

String countryCode = request.getParameter("country");
String countryName = countries.get(countryCode);
// ...
```

Or to display plain in JSP:

```
<p>Country code: ${param.country}</p>
<p>Country name: ${countries[param.country]}</p>
```

Or to pre-select the dropdown:

```
<select name="country">
  <c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country">
    <option value="${country.key}" ${param.country == country.key ? 'selected' : ''}>${country.value}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for editing and answering the question...I was a bit confused how to put my question.. Can't we write a seperate POJO for dropdown box and access selected value using <jsp:formBean> <jsp:setProperty> and <jsp:getProperty> on the JSP page?? Kindly reply

Answer (score -3):

**This can be done without storing anything on server side.**

```
<select name="menu" id="menu">
<option value="1">label 1</option>
<option value="2">label 2</option>
</select>

<button onclick='show()'>Click me</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function show(){
var theContents = document.getElementById('menu')[document.getElementById('menu').selectedIndex].innerText;
window.alert(theContents);
}
</script>
```